# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am not able to figure out the error over here: I am using Gecko 0.16 with Selenium 3.4 on Saucelabs with FF54.

Here is the console output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
14:19:13 Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
14:19:13 System info: host: 'jenkins-big-slave001.clearslideng.com', ip: '10.170.113.99', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
14:19:13 remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
14:19:13    0:           0x4f99ad - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h45ace4059cd74233
14:19:13    1:           0x4f9e92 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::hb5a725a088a2a2fc
14:19:13    2:           0x439c38 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h3eac9ab4802e2cd0
14:19:13    3:           0x442539 - <geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler as webdriver::server::WebDriverHandler<geckodriver::marionette::GeckoExtensionRoute>>::handle_command::hec53c2ea4656249d
14:19:13    4:           0x434924 - webdriver::server::start::{{closure}}::he5e71944552dea53
14:19:13    5:           0x405f87 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h061d4025362f1291
14:19:13    6:           0x5b567a - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
14:19:13                         at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98
14:19:13    7:           0x416fd7 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::hf93806550e6c682e
14:19:13    8:           0x5ade94 - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
14:19:13                         at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:624
14:19:13                          - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
14:19:13                         at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
14:19:13                          - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
14:19:13                         at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
```

Comment: Please show us your code? and at which point the error occurs?

Comment: Error `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` says it all. Check the initialization of WebDriver instance

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same problem. Just update to latest versions. At the moment of writing this, FF 56.0.1, Gecko 0.19.0 WebDriver 3.6.0